# Mongoose: Find SubDocument And Modify It's Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically I am trying to create a command in Shotgun npm module for Node.js that finds a user in a database, and bans him if he exists.

This is a sample user entry (users are stored in a collection called 'users'):

```
{
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("536d1ac80bdc7e680f3436c0"),
"joinDate" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:13:28.079Z"),
"lastActiveDate" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:13:48.918Z"),
"lastSocketId" : null,
"password" : "Johndoe6",
"roles" : [], //the 'banned' will goe here, ex. ['banned']
"username" : "johndoe6"
}
```

This is my command js code:

```
exports.roles = 'mod, admin'; //this command is only to be used by users who are admins or mods
exports.description = "Sets the specified user's ban status."; //info for help menu
exports.usage = "<USER>"; //also more help into
exports.options = { //start of username prompt
    username: { //name of the option
    required: true,
    prompt: "Please enter a user username to edit.",
    noName: true,
    hidden: true,
    validate: /^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i,
},
confirm: { //this is a yes/no prompt for adding to the array
description: "Confirms user ban.",
validate: function (confirm, shell, options) {
        var confirmRegex = /^y(es)?|true$/i;
        options.confirm = confirmRegex.test(confirm);
        return options.confirm ? true : "User ban canceled.";
    }
}
};
 exports.invoke = function (shell, options) { //shotgun thing
 shell.db.users.find({ "username" : options.username }); //find username based on what was plugged in for 'options.username' which was our prompt
 if (err) return shell.error(err);
 if (!user) return shell.error("No user with username {{0}} exists.".format(options.username));
 shell.getCurrentUser(function (currentUser) { 
        // If user did not supply confirm already then set the CLI text to edit and          prompt for user confirm.
       if (options.username.isModOrAdmin()){ //check if a user has 'mod' or 'admin' in array 'roles'
        return shell.error("You cannot ban other mods or admins".format(options.username))
}
if (!options.confirm) {
            shell.log("Modify user {{0}} confirm.".format(options.username));
            shell.setPrompt('confirm', 'editUser', options);
        }
        else {
            // If we have user confirm then modify the user.
            user.username = options.confirm;
                    if (err) return shell.error(err);
                    shell.db.users.update({ "username" : options.username }, {$addToSet: {roles: "banned"}}); //go into the database, find the user we typed into the prompt and add a 'banned' into its 'roles' array
                    shell.log("User {{0}} banned        successfully.".format(options.username)); //notify command user that ban happened
                        };
                    });
            };
```

As you can see this is the basic gist, I am just having problems with finding the user to check if he exists, and modifying his array. How can I change this code so that the text typed into the username prompt is then used to search the database for an existing user in 'users' collection of my database and then 'banned' added to his 'roles' array?

EDIT: I now realize that I just need to convert those to Mongoose
I got the first part down I think,
shell.db.User.findOne({ username: options.username }, function (err, user) {
this finds the user based on the prompt, which is of course options.username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do requested operation in mongoDb Shell you need to call:

```
db.users.findAndModify({"username" : options.username},
                       [],
                       {$addToSet: {roles: "banned"}},
                       {'new':true}
);
```

Comment: What would this look like in mongoose?